# ¿Por qué esta línea muestra "Invalid type conversion"?

Tags: c, punteros, embebido

Tengo esta pieza de código C (Para plataformas MSP430, compilador cl430):

```
void function(uint8_t * x){
    // Esta variable está definida en el archivo linker file como "X_ADDR = 0xE000;"
    extern uint32_t X_ADDR; 
    uint16_t i = 0;
    uint16_t size = 10;
    uint32_t dst_addr = (uint32_t) &X_ADDR; 

    for (i=0; i < size; i++){
         *((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x+i); // <-- Esta línea muestra la advertencia
}
```

Lo que entiendo es esto, aunque creo que estoy equivocado aquí:

```
*((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x + i);
                |       |       |   |
                V       V       V   V
*((uint8_t *) (u32  + u16)) = *(u8*+u16);
       *((uint8_t *) (u32)) = *(u8*);
                     *(u8*) = u8;
                         u8 = u8;
```

Esta plataforma es de 16-bits pero soporta un modo extendido de direccionamiento de 20-bits.

¿Alguna opinión al respecto? y ¿Cómo debería ser escrito?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el código está pensado para un modelo de memoria extendida, con punteros de 20-bits (uint32_t), pero este no estaba activado y usaba el modo de punteros de 16 bits.

Activándolo o cambiando `uint32_t dst_addr = (uint32_t) &X_ADDR;` a `uint16_t` o `uintptr_t`, ya no genera el mensaje de advertencia.

Answer (score 2):

Los compiladores advierten de la *posiblemente no intencionada* pérdida de precisión en la conversión:

> [clang](https://tio.run/##VZDbasMwDIavp6cQ7MZOyJpuMAZJBzv1NYqx3U3gOMOHkK3kkfYUe7BMDTtVV9IH@n4hXWmn/PM8n5PXLhuLbUyGfLp4uQUYejK4z14n6r3IjG92CQsc5QGQ60jW14wIN1g3pyzSu2W8/sevLpmbmHbKmHBcGet6u727f3hscLVCk7vuDQflsoVlZ98HFLSpGw5oFyF3ZfmdvlQh/u6SKH7kJUnJAYUYuVvkbVXhU0wK3eeHtwq7bGMKPCpUZrAhWa9JLeIJJgCWYqfICwkHOPt9gs/OvaYgG5jm@Qs)
>
> cast to `uint8_t *` (aka `unsigned char *`) from smaller integer type `unsigned int` [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

> [gcc](https://tio.run/##VY9NasMwEEbXnVN80I1k4yZpoRTiZNdzBCEpdMCWgyWZNMFH6il6MHcq@jurb540byRvT6fGLsstB9tl59HG5Diku5c90TSwwzEHm3gIKgt@OiRUOOsrQeqTbB4FMXZYb/@zyBcvePOHP9wLdzEdjHNjGcFqBZf7/hWT6bKncvU4jFC8k1NGWzyS6vpraalK/T5HQ307a9ZavJU6SyrytmnwHJNB9/4WvEGffUyjtAbGTX5MPlg2RTzTTCRS9IaD0nSlm5@/r/WW5mX5AA)
>
> cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

---

Los punteros suelen tener el tamaño de la [palabra de procesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palabra_(inform%C3%A1tica)). En [arquitecturas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_de_computadoras) de 64 bits será un entero de 64 bits (`[u]int64_t`) que será más grande que el tamaño de `int` (que habitualmente es representado por `[u]int32_t`).

Por eso da una alarma al convertir tipos de diferentes tamaños, compruébalos:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define T(X) printf("Tamanyo de " #X " = %d\n", sizeof(X))

int main()
{
    T(uint8_t);   // Tamanyo de uint8_t = 1
    T(uint16_t);  // Tamanyo de uint16_t = 2
    T(uint32_t);  // Tamanyo de uint32_t = 4

    T(uint8_t*);  // Tamanyo de uint8_t* = 8
    T(uint16_t*); // Tamanyo de uint16_t* = 8
    T(uint32_t*); // Tamanyo de uint32_t* = 8
}
```

Para evitar el problema haz que `dst_addr` sea un puntero, que al fin y al cabo es lo que quieres:

```
void function(uint8_t * x){
    uint16_t i = 0;
    uint16_t size = 10;
    uint32_t* dst_addr = 0; // dummy value
//  ^^^^^^^^^ <--- Puntero

    for (i=0; i < size; i++){
         *((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. He añadido un poco mas de detalle. En cuanto al tratar la variable como puntero, prefiero hacer la aritmética con enteros ya que al final necesito escribir a nivel de bytes (8 bits). Aquí está la [pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751519/why-is-this-showing-invalid-type-conversion) si quieres revisar la discusión allí.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh los detalles que has añadido no cambian la respuesta. Si quieres quitar la alarma usa punteros. Si estás usando enteros para tratarlos como punteros, obtendrás alarmas, independientemente de lo que prefieras.